# How can I call winrar in perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, compression, winrar

Is it possible to call winrar through perl on a windows system, such as

perl -e "rar a -rr10 -s c:\backups\backup.rar @backup.lst"

If so, is there a more efficient way to do this?

I've looked up "perl -e" +winrar on google, however none of the results gave me any answer that was remotely close to what i was looking for. The system Im running this on is a Windows XP system. Im open to doing this in another language like python if its easier, however I am more comfertable with perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to execute external commands from a Perl script is to use [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
my $cmd = 'rar a -rr10 -s c:\backups\backup.rar @backup.lst';
if (system $cmd) {
    print "Error: $? for command $cmd"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access the RAR facilities in Windows using the CPAN module [Archive::Rar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive::Rar):

```
use Archive::Rar;
my $rar = Archive::Rar->new(-archive => $archive_filename);
$rar->Extract();
```

Answer (score 1):

To use external applications from your Perl program, use the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) builtin.

If you need the output from the command, you can use the backtick (``) or qx operator as discussed in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). You can also use pipes as discussed in [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC).

Comment: Would I still need to set the env like:

$ENV{winrar} = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\"; 

or can I skip that using system